# SearchView with or without Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, searchview

I want to implement a search within my app. I plan to do offline(within an external SDK) and online search with JSON-Requests realized with Volley. First I used `AutoCompleteTextView` but now I want to switch to the more suitable `SearchView`. But I did not find out whether it is better to implement with an `android.intent.action.SEARCH` Intent or if I just implement the `SearchView` listener methods. Which option should I prefer?